# CKEditor5 prevent nesting of specific AttributeElements

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I forked the [ckeditor5-link plugin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-link) to be able to create custom links. But when I try to nest different types of links (example below), ckeditor can't handle the prevention of nesting anymore, because the links have different tags.

**Example 1**: Using same tags

1. Write: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." in the editor
2. Select "ipsum dolor sit" and create a custom link tag ("mylink").
3. Select "dolor" and create a custom link tag ("mylink").

The result would be

```
<p>
  Lorem
  <mylink href="1">ipsum </mylink>
  <mylink href="2">dolor</mylink>
  <mylink href="1"> sit</mylink>
  amet.
</p>
```

This behavior is correct.

**Example 2**: Using different tags

1. Write: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." in the editor
2. Select "ipsum dolor sit" and create a default link tag ("a").
3. Select "dolor" and create a custom link tag ("mylink").

The result will be

```
<p>
  Lorem
  <a href="1">
    ipsum
    <mylink href="2">dolor</mylink>
    sit
  </a>
  amet.
</p>
```

but it needs it to be

```
<p>
  Lorem
  <a href="1">ipsum </a>
  <mylink href="2">dolor</mylink>
  <a href="1"> sit</a>
  amet.
</p>
```

I hope, you all understand what I need.
How can i achieve this behavior?

Comment: The correct place to ensure that on a single fragment of text only one link type is applied is the model. Simply, only one text attribute can be set on that fragment. That can partially be defined in the schema (see https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1239#issuecomment-421318938) but you may also need to [register a post-fixer](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_document-Document.html#function-registerPostFixer) to fix remaining scenarios.

Comment: Thank you Reinmar, let's see if I can do it. :)